# In Which file of X Cart 5 we can put insert into query

Tags: database, x-cart

In X cart how can we put insert into command.

And also in which specific file?

Answer (score 2):

X-Cart 5 uses [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) to work with database records. It adds a few wrapper classes for easier programming, but most of the documentation available for Doctrine applies to X-Cart 5 too.

Also, you can find a great article on adding custom X-Cart 5 database entities [here](http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Creating+new+entity+--+Introduction+of+editable+ItemsList+in+admin+area).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a controller file and create any method and do your logic here like and get this details in tpl file Like `getRecords()` :

```
public function getRecords(){

$options = \XLite::getInstance()->getOptions('database_details');
  // do your connection login
  // do your query logic 
}
```